# Highcharts style behavior difference between 2 highcharts sources

Tags: javascript, highcharts, styles

We are trying to integrate highcharts with our styles

When using code from https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js it works, but when using code from https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js we have problems.

```
//good
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>

//bad
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Take a look at the working version found here: https://codepen.io/alfein/pen/YLevxo.  Not modify the HTML to load highcharts from https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js (no js subfolder).  Notice that the color of pie slice for 'Bananas' no longer matches that of the Legend.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Highcharts documentation [Sytled Mode](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) for styling using CSS that was introduced with Highcharts 5.

The bottom line is that the "classic mode" files are directly in the root folder, the CSS files are in a js sub-folder.

Comment: Thank you.  Would you know how to reference the classic mode from npm?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to reference classic mode from npm.

Comment: Actually we found out - same way there's a root folder and a js folder as well.